# Deploy docker compose on Azure Container App

Tags: azure, docker-compose, azure-container-registry, azure-container-apps

from [ACA docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/container-apps/get-started?tabs=bash) we have to specify target port of the container

```
az containerapp create \
  --name my-container-app \
  --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP \
  --environment $CONTAINERAPPS_ENVIRONMENT \
  --image mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/containerapps-helloworld:latest \
  --target-port 80 \
  --ingress 'external' \
  --query configuration.ingress.fqdn
```

Now my question is how to deploy via docker-compose not just a single image, since there is a single target-port?

Comment: did you find a solution yet to add multiple docker images in the containerApp pod?

Comment: @JoelHarkes I switched to ACI

Comment: Nice to know, thanks! im looking into it myself.

Comment: @Yefet, I know this is long after you deployed it, but doesn't ACI limit you to a single container image? How are you using it to deploy multiple images that work together similarly to docker-compose?
EDIT: I stand corrected. Microsoft has a tutorial showing how to deploy a docker-compose solution seamlessly into ACI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/tutorial-docker-compose

Comment: @RonaldB Correct! I used that turo as a reference

Answer (score 7):

To deploy with docker-compose, you can use this command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/compose

```
az containerapp compose create --environment
                               --resource-group
                               [--compose-file-path]
                               [--location]
                               [--registry-password]
                               [--registry-server]
                               [--registry-username]
                               [--tags]
                               [--transport]
                               [--transport-mapping]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to deploy multiple containers to a single container app, you can define more than one container in the configuration's **containers** array

**Reference**: [Containers in Azure Container Apps Preview | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/container-apps/containers)

### Alternative

If you want to deploy your application via Docker Compose, you can deploy to **Azure Web app**

While creating the web app, select publish as **Docker Container**. Under Docker, select options as **Docker Compose** and provide the Docker Compose file

[image]

Comment: Azure Web Apps is a completely different service than Azure Container Apps.